# PHP get date as Unix Epoch time

Tags: php, datetime, twitter

I just got some tweets using their XML feed, and have gotten the date/times like so

> Tue Sep 29 22:30:51 +0000 2009

I tried using `strtotime()` on this, but it wasn't producing the correct results.

I later on use

```
echo date($dateTimeFormat, $twitterUnixTime);
```

I know I could use a regex, but from the looks of it it will be complicated (and will need to use a callback, to convert 'Sep' to a numeral. From what I understand, `strtotime()` can easily do MySQL dates (2009-09-30 13:00:00) and some others (generally from RSS feeds).

What can I do here to get this date/time as an Unix Epoch time?

**UPDATE**

Here is my code

```
$dateTime = $status->created_at; // Tue Sep 29 22:30:51 +0000 2009

$date = strtotime($dateTime);

$dateTimeFormat = 'j/n/y g:ia';

echo date($dateTimeFormat, $date); // 2/2/09 12:01am
```

**UPDATE**

Sorry guys, entirely my fault. I have a variable mistyped. Thanks for your answers!

Comment: `strtotime()` worked just fined for me.

Comment: Which PHP version are you using?  In my experience, some older versions contain strtotime() versions that are slightly more finicky...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is exactly the problem you are getting with `strtotime` ?

Using this code :

```
$str = 'Tue Sep 29 22:30:51 +0000 2009';
$ts = strtotime($str);

var_dump(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $ts));
```

I get this output :

```
string '2009-09-30 00:30:51' (length=19)
```

So, wrong by 2 hours -- is that the kind of problem you have ?

If yes, it might be a problem of timezone : I am in France, and there is a difference of 2 hours with GMT/UTC time.

Changing locale with the [`date_default_timezone_set`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) function *(to set one that is in the GMT timezone)*, with this line before the previous ones :

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
```

Gets this as output :

```
string '2009-09-29 23:30:51' (length=19)
```

Which kind of look like the desired result ?

You might also change the [`date.timezone`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone) setting in `php.ini` ; but might have some other impacts, so not sure it's that much of a good idea...

Maybe you could use the "`UTC`"  timezone, btw, like this :

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

Considering what we are willing to get/mean, it might actually be a better idea...

Comment: You can also use `gmdate()` to get the GMT/UTC date without changing timezones.

Comment: "So, wrong by 2 hours?" that's not wrong at all, it's showing the exact same moment in time in your timezone

Comment: by "wrong", I meant "not what you might expect", actually -- thanks about gmdate !